# adress of local variable returned warning in a function that returns char array

Tags: c++

Why this causes a warning?

```cpp
char *decToBin(unsigned long n)
{
  char bin[sizeof(n)*8+1];
  int i=0;
  while(n)
  {
    bin[i]=(char)(n%2+'0');
    n/=2;
    i++;
  }
  return bin;
}
```

The warning is:

```cpp
address of local variable 'bin' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

It is a decimal to binary converter that returns a char array

Comment: `bin` is a local variable and returning an address to it is undefined behaviour, return `std::string` instead

Comment: The memory of the variable on the stack is recycled when the function returns and subsequent calls of any functions can and will overwrite the memory contents at that location.

Comment: How to solve this?

Comment: return a `std::string` instead, it takes care of the necessary memory allocations

Comment: String is not in my syllabus. I'm instructed to use arrays.

Comment: Did your class not teach you how to avoid this kind of problem? There are potential solutions ranging from `std::string` to dynamic allocation to static/global variables to changing it so the caller provides the array to the function instead of the function creating the array. In real world code the usual best answer would be to use `std::string` but if you can't do that, then chances are you have other limitations too which we would be unaware of.

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't know it. But only char array is in my whole book about string. also it uses cstring or string.h instead of string library